# Display result in 1 row in LIST STYLE

Tags: php, html

Here my code for retrieve data and display an image gallery using

in 1 row.

```
<?php
require('database_connection.php');
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $latest_tyres = "SELECT IMLITM, BRAND, PATTERNS, WIDTH, SZ FROM tblInventory WHERE NOT AR='0' AND LATEST='L'";
    echo "<ul style='list-style:none;display:inline;padding:0'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($latest_tyres)) 
    {

        echo "<li style='width:230px;height:320px;background-color:green'>";
        echo "<div style='width:220xp;height:320px;background-color:black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto'>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    mysqli_close($mydatabase);
?>
```

As the result of the code should produce an HTML like:

```
<ul style='list-style:none;display:inline;padding:0'>
   <li style='width:230px;height:320px;background-color:green'>
       <div style='width:220xp;height:320px;background-color:black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto'>
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But in my HTML it just display empty with this code:

```
<ul style="list-style: none; display: inline; padding: 0px;"/>
```

HERE ARE THE QUERY OUTPUT:

```
===================================================
|  IMLITM  |  BRAND  | PATTERNS  |  WIDTH  |  SZ  |
===================================================
| LRCO095  |  CON    |    R50    |   200   |  16  |
---------------------------------------------------
| LB1111   |  FALKEN |    R70    |   100   |  18  |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does your query return any result ?

Comment: Share the output of var_dump($latest_tyres) here

Comment: @SirBeute Yes..the query i wrote is executed with result. I had tried execute in my database.

Comment: And why in the cycle does not print information obtained by SQL query?

Comment: @user3506410 check again your query. "where **not** AR='0'" is not valid.

Comment: @user3383116  Yes..That what I asking about..as the size given for <li> and <div>. It should have at least some height and width display. But it did not show anything in my screen.

Comment: @Gil Yes..i had change in my code and it also did not show any html structure.

Comment: I still think it's a query problem. Add `print_r($row)` to the loop and if I'm correct you won't see even that, because the query returns empty results and therefore the loop does not run.

Comment: @Gil Yes..it did not show any result. It not execute the loop, because I try ti put alert message inside the loop it did perform any action. But if the alert is outside the loop it showed. I just wonder why i could not execute the loop although i changes the query already.

Comment: @Gil  I think I know where the error. Which I forget to put $result = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $latest_tyres).

Comment: Yeah, missed that as well... I'm so used to access the DB through specific classes I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to use mysqli_query function before the loop starts. https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Use below code.

```
$result = mysqli_query($latest_tyres);
echo "<ul style='list-style:none;display:inline;padding:0'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

{
   // Your html code
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Yes..that what I found just now.Thanks